# java socket generate xml

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a client-server program using java socket. I have some clients and a server. The clients send information about theirs CPU-load to the server, and then all informations from clients are saved by the server into an xml file. Clients send this information periodically (e.g every 5 minutes).

Technically, I have a problem to control and how to fix that after that every client have sent their CPU-load. Anyone can help?
This is part of my codes,

```
public void listenSocket(){ 
        int client=0;
        while(client<2){
            ClientWorker w;
              try{  
                    w = new ClientWorker(server.accept());
                    Thread t = new Thread(w);
                    t.start();
                    CpuLoad[client]=w.getLoad();
                    Ip[client]=w.getIP();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Accept failed: 4444");
                    System.exit(-1);
              }
           client++;
        }

        XmlGenerator xml = new XmlGenerator();

        try{
            xml.generate(CpuLoad, Ip);
            System.out.println("file generated");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Can't generate file");
        }

}
```

I thought that my algorithm was right, but there is still an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
           at server.ServerOne.listenSocket(ServerOne.java:39)
```

this is class of Clientworker

```
class ClientWorker implements Runnable{
    Socket client;
    String ip;
    String load;
    String data[]=new String[7];


    ClientWorker(Socket client){
    this.client = client;
}

public void setIP(String ip){
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public void setData(String load){
        this.load = load;
    }

    public String getIP(){
        return ip;
    }

    public String getData(){
        return load;
    }

public void run(){

    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try{
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
      out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("in or out failed");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

            try{
                String a = in.readLine();
                setData(a);
                String b = client.getInetAddress().toString();
                setIP(b);
        //Send data back to client
                out.println(a);
                System.out.println(a);     
            }catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Read failed");
            }

}

}
```

Comment: your question is too vague to give you any sensible answer. Please post some code and some indication where are you having problems and with what specific point.

Comment: hope this improvement more helping. Thanks @maasg

Comment: Not really. Which is line 39? And when you catch an exception, don't just make up your own error message: use the one that comes with the exception.

Comment: I guess you have concurrency issues: how are you waiting for `ClientWorker` to do its work? You need some sort of synchronization between the worker thread and the main. Could you post the `ClientWorker`  code?

Comment: Don't use sockets for this. This is what HTTP is for. Also, never do this `catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("Can't generate file");}.` It catches all exceptions and throws away the stack trace which means you can't work out what's going on.

Comment: line 39 is `CpuLoad[client]=w.getLoad();` @EJP

Comment: most probably the ClientWorker is not in an operational state when you call `CpuLoad[client]=w.getLoad();` - I ask again, how are you synchronizing the work of a Worker? Could you post the `ClientWorker` code as well?.

Comment: @artbristol thanks dude..but i must do it in socket... :D

Comment: @maasg its more than homework :D.. i think i must learn again about this crazy stuff.. -,-"

Comment: I've tagged it 'homework' to reflect so. I see you're new to SO so we give you some slack :-)

Comment: well @maasg , i really stuck for this problem. i give up. i've read the links you give me. i really stuck. very need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in this code is the lack of a synchronization mechanism between your ClientWorker  and the 'master'. You start a thread for the worker, and 1 instruction later you ask for the result of it's task. It's like a teacher giving you homework and asking for the result a minute later. What would you say? "Sorry I don't have it", or translated to your code, "Null Pointer Exception".

You need a way to let the Worker do its work. You ask for the result only after the worker has something to report.
This being homework, I will not complete your code. You should look into:

- [Thread Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)
- [Wait/Notify](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306)
- [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

And my favorite:

- [Java Concurrency API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

The best book I've read on this topic:

- [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/)

Feel free to post new questions on specific issues.

Comment: well @maasg , i really stuck for this problem. i give up. i've read the links you give me. i really stuck. very need help.